# Concise Golang way to search key property within slice of an object

Tags: function, go, slice, function-pointers, functor

I created 3 search functions:

```golang
func containsRole(x string, a []Role) bool {
    for _, n := range a {
        if x == n.Name {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func containsWorkflow(x string, a []SuperWorkflow) bool {
    for _, n := range a {
        if x == n.Workflow.Name {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func containsPermission(x string, a []Permission) bool {
    for _, n := range a {
        if x == n.URN {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I'm calling them in a loop in 3 other different functions like:

```golang
// In function 1
for _, leftRole := range leftRoles {
    if !containsRole(leftRole.Name, rightRoles) {
        createRoleReport(leftRole))
    }
}
// In function 2
for _, leftWF := range leftWorkflows {
    if !containsWorkflow(leftWF.Workflow.Name, rightWorkflows) {
        createWorkflowReport(leftWF)
    }
}
// In function 3
for _, leftPerm := range leftPermissions {
    if !containsPermission(leftPerm.URN, rightPermissions) {
        createPermissionReport(leftPerm)
    }
}
```

The properties of structs: `Role.Name`, `SuperWorkflow.Workflow.Name` and `Permission.URN` are `string` unique keys.
Is there a concise way in Golang, using function pointer or something, to use only one function instead of 3 `containsRole()`, `containsWorkflow()`, and `containsPermission()` and reduce duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the cleanest and most efficient solutions until generics arrive.

> The properties of structs: `Role.Name`, `SuperWorkflow.Workflow.Name` and `Permission.URN` are `string` unique keys.

You could sort the slices by the unique key, so you could use binary search when looking for an element, see [`sort.Search()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search).

Also you could store them in a map, mapped from the unique key, and the `contains` operation becomes a simple map indexing, e.g. `!containsRole()` would be:

```
if _, ok := roles[x]; !ok {
    // there is no role with Name == x
}
```

This map lookup will be superior in speed compared to your sequential search algorithm, and will most likely beat the binary search too.

(You wouldn't have to add a function for it of course, just index the map where you need to know if `x` is contained in it.)

Comment: Another possible approach would be creating an interface with a `Len() int` and `Get(i int) string` function and implementing the contains function once for the interface (similar to how [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) and [`sort.Sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort))

Comment: @Leon Yes, but it's nowhere near shorter. You would have to do that for all slice types, e.g. `[]Role`, `[]SuperWorkflow` and `[]Permission`, which is already more than the asker's example.

Comment: Yes, the map is the best solution ... long refactoring needed.